# Custom header not inserted in request in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, http-headers

There's a thrird party app that needs to get information via custom http headers, so I wrote a simple test app that creates this headers and then redirects to a page that lists all headers.

The header-generating servlet snippet is:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setHeader("cust-header", "cust-val");
    response.sendRedirect("header.jsp");
}
```

On the other hand, the relevant code from header.jsp is:

```
<%
    Enumeration enumeration = request.getHeaderNames();
    while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
    String string = (String)enumeration.nextElement();
    out.println("<font size = 6>" +string +": " + request.getHeader(string)+ "</font><br>");
    }
    %>
```

That displays the following headers:

```
Host: localhost:9082
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; es-ES; rv:1.9.2.10) Gecko/20100914 Firefox/3.6.10 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: es-es,es;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:9082/HdrTest/login.jsp
Cookie: JSESSIONID=0000tubMmZOXDyuM4X9RmaYYTg4:-1
```

As if the custom header was never inserted. How can I fix it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a **redirect** you're basically instructing the client (the webbrowser) to fire a brand new HTTP request. A brand new request also means a brand new response. Replace it by a **forward**:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("header.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Or if you actually want to have it on the redirected request, then create a `Filter` which is mapped on `/header.jsp` and modifies the header accordingly.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ((HttpServletResponse) response).setHeader("foo", "bar");
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Also note that you're displaying the **request** headers in the `header.jsp` instead of **response** headers. Since there's no direct API avaliable to display the response headers, you'd like to investigate them using an external HTTP header sniffing tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) (the [*Net*](http://getfirebug.com/network) panel) or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply; I changed the code to: response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        response.setHeader("cust-header", "cust-val");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("header.jsp").forward(request, response);
        But still the custom header is not listed in the headers.

Comment: You're listing the `request` headers instead of `response` headers. I'd suggest to use Firebug to check them.