# How to pass a custom request header to redirect page in spring-mvc

Tags: http, spring-mvc, servlets, http-headers

I have to pass a token (string) in a HTTP request header to a 3rd party web application.
 ie from my java web application, I will set the HTTP request header value and the 3rd party web application will receive the HTTP request header.

I have successfully set the request header from my Spring MVC controller and verified it 
 by redirecting it to a simple jsp file in the same application.

Then I tried perform a Redirect to the simulated 3rd party web application , Unfortunately the token request header is never displayed on the simulated 3rd party web application.

I believe that I am setting the request header correctly so the problem might be with the way  I am attempting to transfer it to the simulated 3rd party web application.

Here's the code I used in my spring Controller for redirection,

```
HttpServletRequest request = new CustomHttpServletRequest(httprequest);

CustomRedirectView rv = new CustomRedirectView();

rv.sendRedirect(request, response, "redirectUrl", true);
```

where CustomHttpServletRequest - class which extends HttpServletRequestWrapper  and i have overridden getHeader method as per my requirement

```
    CustomRedirectView - class which extends RedirectView
    redirectUrl - redirect url for the 3rd party web application
```

I will be really grateful for any help or advice on this challenge.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763015/custom-header-not-inserted-in-request-in-servlet

Comment: thanks for reply. i have gone through the link you suggested. but its not meeting my requirement. I can't go for requestDispatcher.forward() because my redirect url is in a different context (application). also if i use forward(), the url will not change in the address bar. is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: It's there in the same question, create a filter mapped to the redirected url and add the custom header. check answer by @BalusC